# how to get doxygen to produce call & caller graphs for c functions

Tags: c, doxygen

I've spent some time reviewing the docs and going through my doxy config file from end to end.  I cut doxygen loose on my config file and it produces documentation and indices for structs and cpp classes but I don't see call or caller graphs for the multitude of c functions in my source tree.

Can anybody tell me how to configure doxygen to produces these call and caller trees ?  I do have graphviz installed.

Comment: Can you please add the output from doxygen

Answer (score 65):

You have to set `HAVE_DOT`, `CALL_GRAPH` and `CALLER_GRAPH` to `YES`.
Also make sure the path to `dot` is in your `PATH` variable.

If that still doesn't work, you might have to set `EXTRACT_ALL` and/or `EXTRACT_STATIC`, depending on your functions.

Comment: Apologies, I do have HAVE_DOT, CALL_GRAPH, and CALLER_GRAPH set to YES.  By "PATH variable" I assume you mean in my shell because there doesn't appear to be one in my doxy cfg file.  Yes, dot is in my path (i.e. 'which dot' works).  I had not set EXTRACT_ALL or EXTRACT_STATIC.  From the comments it doesn't seem like these would be relevant but I'm trying now.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: If for some reason doxygen can't find dot, you can manually set the path via `DOT_PATH` in your Doxyfile.

Comment: This worked for me too. I'm disappointed that the Doxygen developers haven't thought through the default configuration values more carefully.

Comment: `EXTRACT_ALL` and `EXTRACT_STATIC` worked for me too.

Comment: Yes, EXTRACT_* were also missing in mine.

Answer (score 12):

For MacOS users:

Install Doxygen and Graphviz as:

```
brew install doxygen
brew install graphviz
```

Go to your project folder, and from Terminal set to this path run

`doxygen -g`

A doxygen file will be generated, named as `Doxyfile`. Go ahead and open up this file in any editor and find these parameters and replace their values to YES at their locations:

```
HAVE_DOT               = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES 
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
```

You can also set name of your project in this Doxyfile. Save the file and then run this command in the terminal:

```
doxygen Doxyfile
```

This will generate two more folders named as `html` and `latex`. Go to the `html` folder and open `annotated.html` to view all details of your project. You will also view png images of the call graphs embedded in the html that are relevant (to some functions/classes for example).

Answer (score 6):

Setting the path to "dot" (/usr/local/bin/) via the "Expert" tab controls in the GUI did the trick!

Answer (score 6):

doxywizard is also useful. It gives you all the options in a GUI. Selecting any option shows quick help about that option.

You might also be interested in `COLLABORATION_GRAPH` or `GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY`.

Quite convenient.

Comment: Sweet! Found them under Expert->Dot in doxywizard. Had to enable HAVE_DOT first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for my C global functions. Enabling CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING did help display callgraphs for some functions, yet not all of them.