# Generating Function Call-Graph Doxygen+Graphviz

Tags: c, doxygen, graphviz, call-graph, doxywizard

How can I generate a function call graph using Doxywizard with Graphviz installed? (I'm aware of [how to get doxygen to produce call & caller graphs for c functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887810/how-to-get-doxygen-to-produce-call-caller-graphs-for-c-functions), but it didn't help)

Currently, I've tried the following config: http://pastebin.com/PjLjwjxU, but I can't find the graphs anywhere (I've never used the tool for this matter, so it may not be a technical issue, but more of a user problem).

Comment: i have used this once, i can't remember every bits but i do remember that you need the `dot` package to use the graphviz generator so you should specify the platform/OS that you are using because you probably do not have something installed in the right way.

Comment: perhaps you are interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373714/generate-calling-graph-for-c-code

Comment: The image of the call graph is in the generated html directory...

Comment: How does this handle indirect function calls?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8, and I know it should be generated in the html folder.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, here's an example: [link](http://imageshack.us/f/546/groupvideogrga4731e24a7.png/), I don't if it's this you're asking for.

Comment: @GCC404: Your link doesn't answer the question of indirect function calls.   If A calls B, it is pretty easy to produce an arc A -> B. If A calls *p, and p happens to contain a pointer to B, one would like an arc A -> B anyway. In a fair size C program, there tend to be a fair number of such indirect calls.  I didn't think Doxygen knew enough about function pointers to figure this out; but I'm asking to find out.

Comment: The pastebin link has expired. This is obviously a strategy to ask the question without leaving the full and interesting information in the long term. Also, who would upvote the only answer when it's a problem of configuration specific to the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By rebooting and removing the DOT_PATH specification, it solved the problem.