# Visual Studio 2017 Community C Dependency Graph

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dependency-management

all!
We are using Visual Studio 2017 Community for C developement.
We would like to be able to see call / dependency graphs of the functions.
From what I saw, other, paid versions have these features. I woulf like to know if there is a way to achieve this in Community version.

So:
1. is this possible?
2. IF possible and if not, what other free, good IDEs allow this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I know the dependency graph is not available in the community edition, you can try doxygen as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887810/how-to-get-doxygen-to-produce-call-caller-graphs-for-c-functions), or you can use [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) which is free for open source contributors.

Comment: Thank you! looks interesting, I will look into it. If you know the answer, can you please tell me if these tools are add-ons to VS, or do I have to independently  load the project into them for analysis?

Comment: doxygen has a VS addon. However it not allow you to generate a specific call graph for a method. With CppDepend you can generate the call graph for each method and there's a VS addon available.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out