# Is there a way to add *called* and *called by* functions within C code comments for Doxygen to pick up?

Tags: c, doxygen, jump-table

I am working on an C project that is principally a command based system.  Most functions are called from a central command handler that parses a command string which then calls the appropriate function via a function pointer stored in a large array (jump table).

Doxygen's parsing can not recognize that this central command handler function as the source of calls for all these "command" functions so it cannot generate *call* or *called-by* graphs.

If possible, I'd like to override that. So my question is; is there a way to add information in comment blocks that tells Doxygen, some a function (say `funcCaller`) calls another function (say `funcCallee`) so it can show up in a call graph?

If not, what is a typical way to document the functionality of such system?

Comment: Related: [how to get doxygen to produce call & caller graphs for c functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8887810/1679849)

Comment: At the moment this is, to the best of my knowledge, not possible in doxygen. The only thing one can do is create you own `\xrefitem` lists (on for called and one for called by), you won't see these  calls in the caller graph though. An interesting issue in this respect might be: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7517 although here still the graph will not be updated, might be an interesting extra extension...